# application not running on emulator

Tags: android, debugging

basically i am trying to run an a simple android  application  and i did all things nnormal but when it comes to starting it on the emulator it's always showing me this error messages can somebody explain where's the bug here ??

```
                      03-23 14:23:31.590: D/AndroidRuntime(611): Shutting down VM
                      03-23 14:23:31.620: W/dalvikvm(611): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40014760)
                      03-23 14:23:31.751: E/AndroidRuntime(611): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                       03-23 14:23:31.751: E/AndroidRuntime(611): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.training.mcuisine/com.training.mcuisine.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                      03-23 14:23:31.751: E/AndroidRuntime(611):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1672)
                      03-23 14:23:31.751: E/AndroidRuntime(611):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1764) 
                      03-23 14:23:31.751: E/AndroidRuntime(611):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:122)
                      03-23 14:23:31.751: E/AndroidRuntime(611):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1002)
                      03-23 14:23:31.751: E/AndroidRuntime(611):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                      03-23 14:23:31.751: E/AndroidRuntime(611):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
                      03-23 14:23:31.751: E/AndroidRuntime(611):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4025)
                      03-23 14:23:31.751: E/AndroidRuntime(611):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      03-23 14:23:31.751: E/AndroidRuntime(611):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
                      03-23 14:23:31.751: E/AndroidRuntime(611):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
                      03-23 14:23:31.751: E/AndroidRuntime(611):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
                      03-23 14:23:31.751: E/AndroidRuntime(611):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                      03-23 14:23:31.751: E/AndroidRuntime(611): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 
                      03-23 14:23:31.751: E/AndroidRuntime(611):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:127)
                      03-23 14:23:31.751: E/AndroidRuntime(611):    at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:75) 
                      03-23 14:23:31.751: E/AndroidRuntime(611):    at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:2876)
                      03-23 14:23:31.751: E/AndroidRuntime(611):    at com.training.mcuisine.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:14)
                      03-23 14:23:31.751: E/AndroidRuntime(611):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
                      03-23 14:23:31.751: E/AndroidRuntime(611):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1301)
                      03-23 14:23:31.751: E/AndroidRuntime(611):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1022)
                      03-23 14:23:31.751: E/AndroidRuntime(611):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
                      03-23 14:23:31.751: E/AndroidRuntime(611):    ... 11 more
```

and that is my android manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.training.mcuisine"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.training.mcuisine.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.training.mcuisine.jus"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and that is the activity code for MainActivity

```
                package com.training.mcuisine;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity  {


Intent jusIn = new Intent(MainActivity.this,jus.class);


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    ImageButton jus  = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.jus);



    jus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(jusIn);

        }

    });


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}



}
```

and that is the only other simple branch i kept only the content view just to know what is the problem

package com.training.mcuisine;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
public class jus extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.jus);
}
```

}

Comment: Have you included a reference to that Activity in your Android manifest file?

Comment: and there it is my android manifest i can not see here's the problem

Comment: @AbdelhadiKhiati post the activity code. seems there is problem in initializing and context being null

Comment: @Raghunandan okay  iwill edit the question

Comment: @Raghunandan take a look now .

Comment: @AbdelhadiKhiati answered it will work now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change

```
 Intent jusIn = new Intent(MainActivity.this,jus.class);
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

To

```
Intent jusIn;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
jusIn = new Intent(MainActivity.this,jus.class);
```

Comment: I just know that i can not thank you enough i'm truggling with it for more than 4 hours .
Can you explain to me why it was not working for the declarations of intents ??